# Response header Age control

Tags: angular, wordpress, api, .htaccess, ionic-framework

I have installed WordPress for API serviced and used Ionic 3 and Angular for front end work, both are placed in different web server and it's working fine but whenever I have updated something in the post, It's doesn't reflect the current post, it's showing old unmodified post. So I have opened the local development files and run the serve command, Now it's showing modified file in the local machine but In the production URL I did a hard refresh, clear cache and tried in the different browser still it's showing old content. So I go to the network tab in chrome and found something, Response header Age time is showing 55752, that's mean I can't see the modified file before this time while in the local server I found Age: 12326. So my question is how can I set minimum age time so I can see always fresh content on my PWA website.

I have attached two response images for better understanding -

GET -

[image]

OPTIONS -

[image]

Comment: This request is a preflight OPTIONS request, required for CORS. What are the cache headers on the subsequent GET request ?

Comment: updated my question for better understanding.